# How to set body background image within component in Svelte?

Tags: css, svelte, svelte-component

I have a (pure) Svelte component which acts as a layout page. And I want this layout page have a background image. But when I set the `background-image` to body in the styles of this component it is not being applied as the body is in some parent component.
When I use `:global(body)` it is applied to all layout pages which is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a sandbox or a REPL of your problem?

Comment: https://svelte.dev/repl/83b263da64504c80a7811675833671bf?version=3.38.3

Just note the `:global(body)` vs `body` in styles declaration in *ImageLayout.svelte*. The aim is to have background image on body when the *LoginPage* is displayed but not when the *MainPage* is displayed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this behaviour by using `body` since it's a parent of `ImageLayout` and there is no css parent selector. However you can add an absolute positionned `div` in this layout that has this image in the backgound. Give him all the `height` and `width` possible and use a negative `z-index` to put it behind the content and you have the expected result:

```html
<h1>
    Image Layout
</h1>
<div class="image"></div>
<slot></slot>

<style>
  .image {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-image: url("https://st3.depositphotos.com/4478807/19082/i/450/depositphotos_190824428-stock-photo-white-geometric-hexagonal-abstract-background.jpg");
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>
```

Have a look at the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b0c85e0210d4bf1805821a01f59f790?version=3.38.3).